# Usar tags Twig con React Js

Tags: django, reactjs, twig

estoy usando Django que usa Twig para renderizar los templates.

Lo que quiero hacer es poner un elemento que me sirve Django en el código de React de la siguiente manera:

```
var usuario = {{usuario}};
```

Pero no me deja. No hay alguna especie de tag {verbatim} que anule los tags '{' y '}' de React (como tiene Django)?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucioné el problema, generé un `<script>` en mi HTML donde declaro las variables que necesito como por ejemplo:

```
<script>
    var nombreDeUsuario = {{usuario_nombre}};
    // Declaro el resto de las variables...
</script>
<script>
    // Codigo react usando las variables arriba declaradas
</script>
```

Incluso funciona con  etiquetas como

```
var urlDeSeccion = "{% url 'seccion' %}";
```